# I want to change the screen transition destination based on the number entered in the form

Tags: java, html, mysql, spring, thymeleaf

I started developing with Spring Boot + Thymeleaf + MySQL.

For example, if "1"(DB ID) is entered in the input form,
http://localhost:8080/edit/1
I want to transition to.

But cannot transition the screen by obtaining the value entered in the form.
Please help.

[html]

```
    <form method="post" action="/edit">
    <h1>Please input the number</h1>
    <input type="text" name="id" th:value="${id}" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" >
    <br>
    <a th:href="@{/}">Back enter display</a>
    </form>
```

[Controller]

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView edit(@ModelAttribute MyData mydata, @PathVariable int id, ModelAndView mav) {
        mav.setViewName("edit");
        mav.addObject("title", "edit mydata");
        mav.addObject("id",id);
        Optional<MyData> data = repository.findById((long)id);
        mav.addObject("formModel",data.get());
        return mav;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public ModelAndView update(@ModelAttribute MyData mydata,@PathVariable int id, ModelAndView mav) {
        mydata.setId(id);
        repository.saveAndFlush(mydata);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/searchId", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView searchId(@ModelAttribute("formModel") MyData mydata, ModelAndView mav) {
        mav.setViewName("searchId");
        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/searchId", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView serachId(@PathVariable int id, ModelAndView mav) {
        mav.setViewName("searchId");
        return new ModelAndView("'/edit");
    }
```

[Error Contents]
Enter "1" in the input form and press the "Send" button.
The URL is “http://localhost:8080/edit”
The following error message is displayed.

```
    Whitelabel Error Page
    This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

    Wed Oct 09 19:26:41 JST 2019
    There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
    No message available
```

I confirmed that if I entered the URL directly into the browser, the screen transitions.

Ex)
http://localhost:8080/edit/8

Please tell me how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The form has a fixed action attribute once it reaches the client. Normal form submission won't take the value of an input into account for this matter.

You've two choices, both using javascript.

- Changing the action attribute of your form when the input value changes, binding an onchange event to the input to know when to take the value and modify the action attribute accordingly.
- Intercept the form submission, using preventDefault, and submitting the form manually from javascript with the action attribute modified.

Answer (score 0):

When you use ***HTTP.POST*** to send your form input you should send the form parameters as form data thus you have to read the form values as `@RequestParam("id") Integer id` not as `@PathVariable`. Your controller code should be as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public ModelAndView update(@ModelAttribute MyData mydata, @RequestParam("id") Integer id, ModelAndView mav) {
        mydata.setId(id);
        repository.saveAndFlush(mydata);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I modified and tried as follows.
--
public ModelAndView update(@ModelAttribute MyData mydata, @RequestParam("id") Integer id, ModelAndView mav) {
--

However, the result was a failure and the error content was the same.

I think the html description is wrong.
I especially think the following is wrong:
--
<form method="post" action="/edit">
--

Please tell me how to fix.

Comment: Please check my answer again, i just updated it. Take a look at `@RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)` line especially. I removed {id} part.